# Changing Version String in Linux Kernel sources

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I have downloaded and unzipped the Linux Kernel.
What file(s) in kernel source file(s) are responsible for displaying Version string ??

Thanks !

Comment: What are you really attempting to achieve.  within make menuconfig there is the option to append a string to the version.  This is the correct way of changing 'tagging' your own build.

Comment: @Alistair I am trying to build kernel with my own version string, not through `make menuconfig`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's in the first four lines of the top level Makefile.

Comment: And other files or env. variables - e.g. `CONFIG_LOCALVERSION` in .config and `$KBUILD_BUILD_TIMESTAMP` env. variable, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19362262/how-to-modify-the-linux-kernel-to-change-the-version-string-that-uname-returns